# Testing dump classifier with unseen data

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, pickle, countvectorizer

I trained a classifier and I dump it and dump its vectorizer. Now I want to test it with unseen data by loading the classifier and vectorizer. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

First load your vectorizer back from file:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
vectorizer = joblib.load('your_vectorizer.pkl')
clf = joblib.load('your_classifier.pkl')
```

Then it works the same as before you dumped it to file with pickle. I.e.:

```
vectorized_data = vectorizer.transform(unseen_data)
predictions = clf.predict(vectorized_data)
```

Comment: Thank you Lexxxxx.I believe your code is correct, but the problem now with my computer memory. I am working on Anaconda and it gives me memory error. I think it take the memory of my computer

Comment: Maybe try some feature selection methods (also in sklearn) before you pickle. You can probably reduce the size a lot without decreasing accuracy.